# why does not work ajax that add_action registered in wordpress

Tags: ajax, actions

I create a template page in WordPress and use add_action to define action that use in Ajax.

```
 <?php
/*template name: get_pass
*/
add_filter('wp_ajax_my_action1','mda_get_license');

function mda_get_license(){
    echo 54;
   die();

}
?>
```

and use jQuery code is below:

```
(function( $ ) {
    $(function(){

        $("#btn_code").click(function(){
            showPass($("#input_serial").val());
        });
        function showPass(str) {

            if (str.length != 0) {

                $.post("http://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",{action:'my_action1'},function (response) {

                    alert(response);


                })

            }
        } 

    });

})(jQuery);
```

when i put add_action in function.php of theme the ajax work but when put the add_action in my template file ajax return 0.
i use

```
global $wp_filter;
print_r($wp_filter);
```

to see registered action and saw that two actions registered.
now why do i put `add_action` in my template file the Ajax return 0 while registered action?

Answer (score 1):

The AJAX request is a separate request from the one that renders your page. Your AJAX handler is getting registered on the request that serves the page, but not the AJAX request, which is the one that matters.

Move your `add_action` and function to your theme's `functions.php` file, which loads on *all* requests.

Comment: does not exist any way that i define add_action in my template?

Comment: your template doesn't load on an AJAX request, so your hooked action doesn't exist.